# Redirect user to selected dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown

I want user to be redirected at the basis of option it select. Here is my HTML code the code is already in `example.com/page` and it redirects me on `example.com/page` instead of `example.com/page/1`.Please help me to sort it out

```
<select class="select-mob" id="select" onChange="fire()">
  <option value="1"> Page 1</option>
  <option value="2">Page 2 </option>
  <option value="3">Page 3</option>
</select>
```

And here is my JavaScript

```
function fire() {
  var page = document.getElementByID('select').value;
    if (page = "") {
        window.location = "https://example.com/page"      
     } else {
         window.location= "https://example.com/page/" +page;     
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any specific error? Also try using `page === ""` instead of single `=`.

Comment: Could you check :::

 var page = document.getElementById('select').value;
    if (page == "") {
        window.location = "https://example.com/page"      
     } else {
         window.location= "https://example.com/page/" +page;     
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `=` instead of `==`/`===`.
Also change that `document.getElementByID` to `document.getElementById`.
Here you are:

```
function fire() {
  var page = document.getElementById('select').value;
    if (page == "") {
        window.location = "https://example.com/page"      
     } else {
         window.location= "https://example.com/page/" +page;     
        }
}
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/mostafa-es/pen/gOLdQLN)

Answer (score 0):

You can check this code:

```
 var page = document.getElementById('select').value;
    if (page == "") {
        window.location = "https://example.com/page"      
     } else {
         window.location= "https://example.com/page/" +page;     
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function fire() {
  let page = document.querySelector('select').value;
  page == "" ? window.location = "https://example.com/page" : window.location= "https://example.com/page/" +page; 
}
```